# What is the sign of a damaged solar cell?

Tags: voltage, solar-cell

My panel's open-circuit voltage is 19 V, but when I connect it to the load the voltage lowers to 9 V in full sunlight.

Comment: Solar cell voltage always lowers under load. The higher the load, the lower the voltage. That's why MPPT converters are used to finde the optimal load to extract maximum amount of power from the solar cell. To find out if your cell is damaged or acts according to specs is to take a look at the datasheet where you might find load curves.

Comment: try loads of different sizes to see what it will power, and to plot a V/I diagram.